# Centos 7 Postgresql 9.6 error on replication

Tags: centos-7, postgresql, replication

I've configured replication on postgresql with wal senders. The connection to database from the slave computer works well, but when i tried to execute this sentence to replicate the master server

pg_basebackup -h MasterIP -U postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data -P --xlog

I got this error
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "SlaveIP", user "postgres", SSL off

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of this problem check out the pg_hba.conf because the user with the granted permissions of replication need to be inticated on the file like this

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

host    all         all                 127.0.0.1/32               md5

host    all         all                 LOCALIP/32             md5

host    replication replica             ReplicationIP/32            md5

Hope this can help.